# SettingWithCopyWarning - How do I fix this warning?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, warnings

I am getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning` on the following code:

```py
combined_updated['institute_service'] = combined_updated['institute_service'].copy().astype('float')
```

Could someone in the community help me out in understanding why I keep getting that warning?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas ?

Comment: Thanks. I saw this article initially and it helped me fix the warning with indexing for the following code: ```combined_updated.loc[combined_updated['institute_service']=='Less than 1 year','institute_service']=combined_updated['institute_service'][combined_updated['institute_service']=='Less than 1 year'].str.replace('Less than 1 year', '1.0')``` .  The problem now that I keep getting the same warning on the code that I put in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use copy() to change the column to float; maybe the .copy() is giving you the warning.  You can also try resetting the index before you do the operation, that usually works for me when I get that warning.

```
combined_updated = combined_updated.reset_index(drop=True)
combined_updated['institute_service'] = combined_updated['institute_service'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you @Hammurabi.  Still getting the same warning but with a different message: ```self.obj[item] = s``` .  Any additional help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your post with what self.obj[item] is?  I'm not clear on how you are going from combined_updated to self.obj[item].

Comment: Hello @Hammurabi, This is the cell that is giving me the warning message: ```combined_updated.loc[combined_updated['institute_service']=='7-10','institute_service']=combined_updated['institute_service'][combined_updated['institute_service']=='7-10'].str.replace('7-10', '10.0')
combined_updated = combined_updated.reset_index(drop = True)
combined_updated['institute_service'] = combined_updated['institute_service'].astype(float)```

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell why you are getting the warning, I can't replicate that error.  Also, I don't understand how you can get from that to self.obj[item] == s.  Maybe try just .head(5) and see if you get the error on the first 5 rows, then the first 10, etc.?  Maybe something unexpected is in your df.